# Get zip END header not found while deploying WAR file in Tomcat container

Tags: docker, tomcat, deployment

First, I build a WAR file from servoy platform by following this step

[image]

Then, I start up a Tomcat container by executing

```
docker container run -it -d --name tomcat -p 8081:8080 tomcat:jre17-temurin
```

After fixing the error HTTP Status 404 – Not Found by following this [link](https://www.topzenith.com/2020/07/http-status-404-not-found-docker-tomcat-image.html)

I copied the WAR file from the host to the container

```
docker cp my_war_file.war tomcat:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps
```

Unfortunately, it is not successful and I got the error

```
11-Jul-2023 06:59:28.739 SEVERE [Catalina-utility-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.beforeStart Exception fixing docBase for context [/my_servoy_app]
    java.util.zip.ZipException: zip END header not found
            at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.findEND(Unknown Source)
            at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.initCEN(Unknown Source)
            at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.<init>(Unknown Source)
            ...
```

How can I overcome this issue?